# return string from shell to java file

Tags: java, shell

I have written code in below way.

Java program 1(call shell program) => Shell program => Java program 2 (Will perform encryption).

Hence when I run the Java program 1, it should call shell and followed by java program 2. The java program 2 will return the encrypted value to me and same need to be passed to Java program 1.

When execute shell directly from command prompt, I am getting message like below.

```
[Serverapp01 AESEncryption]$ sh AESEncrypt.sh /keys/keyfile_05.txt texttoencrypt
AESEncrypt.sh: line 28: exit: 0UhSI9LTa/7efiT0quKUsg==: numeric argument required
```

My aim is to get the value `0UhSI9LTa/7efiT0quKUsg==` to my java program 1. But i am not getting this value from shell to java program 1.

Any help is much appreciated.

Java Program 1

```
package com.abc.encrypt;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class AESEncrypt1 {


    public static String callScript(String encryptionScriptPath,String KeyLocation,String textToEncrypt) 
    {
        int value = 0;
        String enc ="Error";
        try 
        {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(encryptionScriptPath,KeyLocation,textToEncrypt);
            Process p = pb.start();
            value = p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                       p.getInputStream()));
                    String line;
                    String temp ="";
                    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                       System.out.println(line);
                       temp = temp + line;
                    }
                    enc=temp;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //value = 2;
            enc = "ErrorOccured.."+e.toString();
        } 

            return enc;
    }

}
```

Shell look like below

```
unset CLASSPATH
KeyLocation=$1
TextToEncrypt=$2
isolatedjreLocation=/AESEncryption/isolatedjre17
JarLocation=/AESEncryption
CLASSPATH="/AESEncryption/isolatedjre17/jre17/bin"
export CLASSPATH
#echo $CLASSPATH

encryptedValue='ErrorInJava'

#echo 'Call Java Program'
encryptedValue=$($isolatedjreLocation/jre17/bin/java -cp $JarLocation/AESCryptoJava_v1.0.0.jar com.abc.AESEncryption $KeyLocation $TextToEncrypt)

#echo $encryptedValue

exit $encryptedValue
```

Comment: Shell must be calling a Java `main()`, which cannot return a value. The main method signature is `public static void main(String[] args)`. You probably need to save data from Java and the let shell read it back.

Comment: The shell `exit` command is supposed to return a value between 0 and 255. Try `echo "${encryptedValue}"` and `exit 0`. You can test with another script (or from commandline): `mySecret=$(encryptionScriptPath); echo "Result: ${mySecret}"`.